Adding variable name to the output file name (html)
I am trying to include a variable name in the html output file name, produced by R Quarto. But no luck so far... In the example below, I specify group name ("Group A"), render, and want the resulting html to be called 'Chart for Group A.html'. Then I want to re-run with a different group name ("Group B") and want the html to be called 'Chart for Group B.html').
Here is what I tried, but getting the following error massage:

Error in quarto_render():
✖ Error running quarto cli.
Caused by error:
! System command 'quarto.exe' failed

---
 fontsize: 20pt
 echo: FALSE
 format: 
  html:
    self-contained: true
---

```{r, include = FALSE}

Group_Name <- "Group A"

library(ggplot2)
library(quarto)

df <- data.frame( Year = c(2020, 2021, 2020, 2021), 
      Var = c(2.01, 3.05, 4.22, 5.29), 
      Group = c('Group A', 'Group A', 'Group B', 'Group B')) 

df <- df[df$Group == Group_Name, ]

```

```{r}

ggplot(df, aes(x=Year, y=Var)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")

```

``` {r}
file_name = paste0("Chart for ", Group_Name, ".html")

quarto_render("TEST output.qmd", output_file = file_name, output_format = "html")
```


You might want to talk a look into parameters: https://quarto.org/docs/computations/parameters.html
